# Give list of packages installed with apt a name

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, dpkg

How can I give a list of packages installed via apt a name, eg. one that I could find with `dpkg-query -W my-packages` or something similar? For example, call the group
`build-essential checkinstall gparted ...` of packages `my-packages`

Rationale: I would like to be able to check if default groups of packages have been installed in my install scripts.

Running Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

The `equivs` package seems to do exactly what I wanted, very simply creating a `.deb` file that can be installed and queried using `dpkg-query`.  See [tutorial](http://terokarvinen.com/2011/create-deb-metapackage-in-5-minutes) for walk-through.

Answer (score 1):

Beside using a meta package I would use a variable:

```
$ packages="coreutils wget"

$ dpkg-query -W $packages
coreutils   8.28-1ubuntu1
wget    1.19.4-1ubuntu2.1

$ echo $?
0
```

Means everything is fine (1) means something is missing.

Find a list of missing packages:

```
$ packages="coreutils wget 0ad pkg1 nonexits"
$ dpkg-query -W $packages 2>&1 > /dev/null | rev | cut -f1 -d' ' | rev
0ad
pkg1
nonexits
```

Comment: useful alternatives, thanks!  The negative is I wouldn't be able to simple check my bundles had been installed from different scripts later on.

Comment: Yeah, it would be messy... Then I guess meta-packages are your best shot.